# Java Beans and JSP. Mini Addition Program

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, javabeans

I am trying to create a small program that takes two number as input from user via MiniAdd.jsp, adds them and then returns it on the same page. I had to make use of Javabeans in JSP. I'm not really sure what I've done. But right now I am running the code and I get [HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error].
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing.

Can someone please help me with where I've gone wrong and what do I need to do? Here's my code so far.

**SumBeans2.java**

```
package add;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SumBean2 implements Serializable {
    
    private int num1;

    private int num2;

    private int sum;
    
    public SumBean2(){
        
    }
    
    public int getNum1() {

        return num1;

    }

    public void setNum1(int num1) {

        this.num1 = num1;

    }

    public int getNum2() {

        return num2;

    }

    public void setNum2(int num2) {

        this.num2 = num2;

    }

    public int getSum() {

        return sum;

    }

    public void setSum(int sum) {

        this.sum = sum;

    }

    
}
```

**MiniAdd.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <%@ page import="add.SumBean2"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>Sum</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="MiniAdd.jsp">

<label>Number 1</label><input type="text" name="num1"><br>

<label>Number 2</label><input type="text" name="num2"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

<jsp:useBean id="SumNumber" class="add.SumBean2" scope="session"/>

<jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num1" value='<%=request.getParameter("num1") %>'/>
<jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num2" value='<%=request.getParameter("num2") %>'/>


</form>

<%

    int sum = 0;

    try {

            sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"))+Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));

    } catch(Exception e) {}

%>

<jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum" value='<%= request.getParameter("sum") %>'/>


Sum = <jsp:getProperty name="SumNumber" property="sum"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The exception message you received should have included stack traces in the Console pointing to what Caused the JasperException. Also, don't catch Exceptions and do nothing with them. At the least, log them or print them. Why not set a breakpoint inside your scriptlet or bean class and debug the JSP to see what's going on?

Comment: 33: <jsp:setProperty name="SumNumber" property="num1" value='<%=request.getParameter("num1") %>'/>
This is where the exception is occuring.